# django remove unicode from query result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Django query gives me below output  format,but i want below format

```
data=`[{'total': 1744, 'name: u'x'}, {'total': 13, 'name': u'm'}, {'total': 126, 'role': name'n'}]`
m=[]
for i in data:
   m.append(i.values())
```

print m
it give me output

```
[[1744,u'x'], [13,u'm'], [126,u'n']]
```

but i need output in
how to remove unicode symbol from output

```
[['x',1744], ['m',13], ['n',126]]
```

how to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `u`? Are you actually trying to convert it to JSON?

Comment: yes i am trying convert it to a json,trying to built a jqplot bar chars for uincode not taking

Comment: 'U' is just for the display's purpose.

Comment: Take a look at python's library `json`: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import json
>>> data=[{'total': 1744, 'name': u'x'}, {'total': 13, 'name': u'm'}, {'total': 126, 'name': u'n'}]
>>> json.dumps([i.values()[::-1] for i in data])
'[["x", 1744], ["m", 13], ["n", 126]]'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the order in which keys will come out of a dictionary (e.g. the order of the values in `i.values()`), so your best bet is to write something like this:

```
m = []
for i in date:
    m.append([i['name'], i['total']])
```

NB: you also mean to be iterating `date`, not `m`, which would be empty in this example. Corrected in my code here.

Comment: thanks you for quick response but how to remove u,support [[u'x',1744], [u'm',13], [u'n',126]]

to [['x',1744], ['m',13], ['n',126]]

Comment: the `u` just indicates that it's a unicode string. It won't show up when you print the string, but does show up when you print the list (as, in that case, it's actually printing `repr(...)` of the elements in the list). It's safe to ignore it unless you know it's causing problems.

Comment: how to ignore them,can you plz add into your answer

Comment: Just ignore them. when you print a `unicode`'s `repr()`, it will show the u to indicate that it's a `unicode` instead of a standard `str`. When you use the value, or display it in a template in Django, it will work as expected.

Comment: Oh, I see you're trying to get this into JSON. In that case, again, ignore it. Python's `json` module will convert `unicodes` to strings in the outputted JSON: `json.dumps({u'key': 1})` => `'{"key": 1}'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str()`.

```
>>> def byte_string(x):
...   return str(x) if isinstance(x, unicode) else x
...

>>> [[byte_string(x) for x in row] for row in d]
[[1744, 'x'], [13, 'm'], [126, 'n']]
```

Note that this code will bomb if you data contains non-ascii string.

Comment: how to change the order?[[ 'x',1744], [ 'm',13], [ 'n',126]]

Answer (score 0):

I used str(jsonVal) to solve this issue. Removed the requirement to use post processing.