# How to use explode in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mezzanine

Hi I have a variable in **django** which contains a **value** something like **((u'rahul',),(u'sdfsd',)(u'fsdfdsf',))** i want to **explode** **u**  from each .....
How can I do this ?

Comment: is that values form Queryset?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is values_list with the flat=True params.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple(tuple(__.encode() for __ in _) for  _ in f)
```

A tuple like `((u'rahul'), (u'sdfsd'), (u'fsdfdsf'))`

will result in `(('rahul',), ('sdfsd',), ('fsdfdsf',))`.

`encode` can accept different encodings like "utf-8", "ascii". The default encoding is `utf-8`. The default way to handle errors is raising a `UnicodeEncodeError`. You can specify "ignore" to `ignore` errors.

Help on `encode` shows this:

> encode(...)
>       S.encode([encoding[,errors]]) -> string or unicode
>
> ```
> Encodes S using the codec registered for encoding. encoding defaults
> to the default encoding. errors may be given to set a different error
> handling scheme. Default is 'strict' meaning that encoding errors raise
> a UnicodeEncodeError. ...
> ```

Comment: +1 for tuples! Django (and Mezzanine) are only Python. You do not need to be a Python hacker to work your way through Learn Python The Hard Way (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/), nor a Django hacker to make it through the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 0):

U means Unicode and if you want to remove u

try this

```
>>>(u'rahul').encode('utf8')
>>> rahul
```

Comment: this is not working actually i want to remove  u dynamically from all values ((u'rahul',),(u'sdfsd',)(u'fsdfdsf',))

Comment: where you displaying the data in html

Comment: then you need to send these result as JSON for that see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263159/django-remove-unicode-from-query-result) and [this also useful](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/)